# Installer for .NET 2.0 application for Windows 98

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0, setup-project

How can an automatic installer for .NET 2.0 application be created for Windows 98?

I mean for application and also for .NET 2.0 if missing.

I tried to do it by creating a setup project for Visual Studio 2008, but I didn't succeed.
I installed IE6 SP1 manually, but Installer still crashed.
Windows Installer 2.0 is installed. It's impossible to install Installer 3.0 there.
I unchecked Installer at Setup Project prerequisites, but still it's not possible to install the application - the error message says that it requires a newer version of Windows.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do *not* use Visual Studio 2008 if you intend to deploy to Windows 9x or ME. VS2008 does not support these operating systems anymore, and if you're stuck with them you should use VS2005 or earlier. Also see this question: [Does Visual Studio 2008 support windows 98?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213711)

Answer (score 1):

According to MS [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907749), Windows Installer 3.0+ is not available for Windows 98.

Running Installer 3.1 setup manually on Windows 98 fails with the message

> Missing entry point for NtOpenProcessToken function

Answer (score 1):

According to this article Win98 is supported for 2.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480241.aspx why not just getting the redistributable from Microsoft?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually update the machine to windows installer 3.x first.  Then it should go.

Comment: Windows Installer 3.0 and up have a hard requirement on a NT lineage operating system. It's not just a matter of "not supported", it's a matter of "cannot be done". The latest Windows Installer version usable on 9x is 2.0.