# .net 2.0 sp1 on Windows 98

Tags: .net-2.0, windows-98

I've been searching around for this and cannot seem to find a solid answer.  I know the 2.0 version of the .net framework is supported in Windows98, but does that include SP1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main difference is that between when .Net 2.0 came out (1/22/2006) and .Net 2.0 sp1 came out (11/19/2007), Microsoft [ended all support for Windows 98](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/support/endofsupport.mspx) (7/11/2006).

That means it would likely work about as well as plain 2.0, but no guarantees will be made and you run it at your own risk.

It also means they're not doing things like security updates for windows 98 any more, so if you have a specific customer in mind who's still running '98 or ME, you might suggest that they upgrade that machine.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the [Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0856EACB-4362-4B0D-8EDD-AAB15C5E04F5&displaylang=en)
supports Windows 98:

Supported Operating Systems: Windows 2000 Service Pack 3; Windows 98; Windows 98 Second Edition; Windows ME; Windows Server 2003; Windows XP Service Pack 2

But [Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1 (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=79BC3B77-E02C-4AD3-AACF-A7633F706BA5&displaylang=en) does not:

Supported Operating Systems: Windows 2000 Service Pack 4; Windows Server 2003; Windows XP Service Pack 2

Comment: Note in 2023: If you happen to need this specific version for Windows 9x, fire up archive.org and put ```http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/7/567758a3-759e-473e-bf8f-52154438565a/dotnetfx.exe``` in WayBack Machine.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft's Download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=79BC3B77-E02C-4AD3-AACF-A7633F706BA5&displaylang=en): No

> Supported Operating Systems: Windows 2000 Service Pack 4; Windows Server 2003; Windows XP Service Pack 2

You can also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310246/installer-for-net-20-application-for-windows98) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

[No, it does not.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=79BC3B77-E02C-4AD3-AACF-A7633F706BA5&displaylang=en#Requirements)