# Are the boost-C++-libraries compatible with win98?

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I know, it sounds ridiculous but I was asked to make an application backwards-compatible with win98. Specifically, I am interested in the boost-thread library that I have used. So, where can I find information about which version of the boost libraries is compatible with which operating system?

Comment: Hang on a sec... Are you still using Win98?  ---- Well, Off the top of my head. Nahhhh, Win98 isn't supported and shouldn't be.....

Comment: It's not me using that operating system :)

Comment: Refuse and explain them why Win98 is a bad idea in 2016.

Comment: This is an entirely reasonable question, that has a clear answer.

Comment: [It is amazing the old systems you can find lying around and still doing useful work.](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/gadgets/a23139/commodore-64-repair-shop/)

Comment: Win'98 doesn't support multi-core systems, which greatly diminishes the value of threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html

It requires XP or newer, and at least VC8.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on which version of Boost you are interested in.

You can go through the [Boost version history](http://www.boost.org/users/history/) and search the *Release Notes* for one that lists a compiler that supports Win98.

A quick search [hints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B) that [this is likely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213711/does-visual-studio-2008-support-windows-98) to be MSVS 2005. This means Visual C++ 8.0.

The latest version of boost that I've found to list this version of VC++ as a supported (and targetted) compiler is [boost 1.52.0](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_52_0.html).

The Boost Thread library has been around since version 1.25.0, so this seems like an acceptable candidate.

Conveniently, the link to [download the source code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.52.0/) (of any particular version) are also provided on the version history page.

Comment: It might be a good idea to dig through the release notes and issue tracker and see if you need to backport any essential fixes for the libraries you will use.

Comment: Supporting MSVS 2005 equals to supporting Win98? I could also imagine that "supporting MSVS 2005" means "supporting MSVS 2005 on WinXP". For sure, I will have a try and if necessary, go back to 1.25.0 ...

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation mentioning that specifically. Considering that the [code](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/boost-1.52.0/src/win32/thread.cpp#L12) seems to request even older version of the API (IIRC Win98 had `WINVER 0x500`), there's a decent chance. Unfortunately I don't have neither the compiler, nor the OS anywhere on hand to test this.